# xamarin forms - populate list view that is inside collection view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms Collection View, inside this collection view is toolkit expander, When someone clicks the header I have binded a command, inside this command I am trying to populate a list view inside the grid of the expander, see code below:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="MathList" HeightRequest="320" SelectionChanged="MathList_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <xct:Expander Command="{Binding GetMathSubCatgories}">
                            <xct:Expander.Header>
                                <Frame Padding="10" Margin="10" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding icon}" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"></Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="{Binding textColor}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </xct:Expander.Header>
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ListView x:Name="SubCatgories" ItemsSource="{Binding subTaskClass}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Frame Padding="10" Margin="10" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <Label Text="aaa" FontAttributes="Bold" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </Frame>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </xct:Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

But in my code behind when I try to populate the list view like so:

```
public ICommand GetMathSubCatgories => new Command(() =>
        {
            Console.Write("Here");

            GetSubTasks(taskcategoryid);

        });

        public async void GetSubTasks(int taskcategory)
        {
            SubCatgories.ItemsSource = await webService.GetMathSubTasks(taskcategory);
        }
```

It says SubCatgories is not available. How would I populate a list view inside the datacollection.

I have also tried this approach, still nothing:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="MathList" HeightRequest="320" SelectionChanged="MathList_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <xct:Expander Command="{Binding GetMathSubCatgories}">
                            <xct:Expander.Header>
                                <Frame Padding="10" Margin="10" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding icon}" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"></Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="{Binding textColor}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </xct:Expander.Header>
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ListView x:Name="SubCatgories" ItemsSource="{Binding subCategories}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Frame Padding="10" Margin="10" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontAttributes="Bold" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </Frame>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </xct:Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Here is the class I am using for the collectionView

```
public class TaskClass
    {

        WebServiceClass webService = new WebServiceClass();

        List<SubTaskClass> subTasks = new List<SubTaskClass>();

        public int taskcategoryid { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public int sortOrder { get; set; }
        public string textColor
        {
            get
            {
                if (name == "Addition")
                {
                    return "#02cc9d";
                }
                else if (name == "Subtraction")
                {
                    return "black";
                }
                else if (name == "Divison")
                {
                    return "#fa5156";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "#23a0b6";
                }
            }
        }
        public List<SubTaskClass> subCategories
        {
            get
            {
                GetSubTasks(taskcategoryid);

                return subTasks;
            }
        }

        public async void GetSubTasks(int taskcategory)
        {
            subTasks = await webService.GetMathSubTasks(taskcategory);
        }
    }
```

and here is the SubTaskClass:

```
public class SubTaskClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int taskcategory { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: first, nesting a ListView inside a CollectionView is a really bad idea and you should avoid it.  However, if you have to do it, you CollectionView ItemsSource should include the nested data you need and you should use binding to set the ListView ItemsSource.

Comment: I did that already, did not do anything, I’ll get an example of what I tried to do there shortly

Comment: @Jason I updated my question

Comment: if you want to load the subcats dynamically you need to use INPC and raise a PropertyChanged event.  Or do like I originally suggested and load all of the subcats with the original data.

Comment: Look in VS' Output pane when the page loads. Is there any error or warning? Also, there is nothing in your code to tell XAML that `subCategories` property will return a different value, when `taskcategoryid` changes. `taskcategoryid` needs to be a property with a backing field. Its setter must include a line that says that "subCategories" property has changed. Read about "property change notification" or "MVVM" or "ViewModel". Find some example where setting one property also changes another property. (And when .Net Maui is final, try MVU. Might be easier to get right than DataBinding/MVVM.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, I do one sample that you can take a look.

```
 <CollectionView
        x:Name="MathList"
        ItemsSource="{Binding catgories}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}"
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xct:Expander Command="{Binding command1}">
                    <xct:Expander.Header>
                        <Frame
                            Margin="10"
                            Padding="10"
                            BorderColor="LightGray"
                            HasShadow="False"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image
                                    HeightRequest="25"
                                    Source="{Binding icon}"
                                    WidthRequest="25" />
                                <Label
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="Large"
                                    HeightRequest="35"
                                    Text="{Binding name}"
                                    TextColor="{Binding textColor}"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </xct:Expander.Header>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ListView x:Name="SubCatgories" ItemsSource="{Binding subtasks}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>


                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Frame
                                                Margin="10"
                                                Padding="10"
                                                BorderColor="LightGray"
                                                HasShadow="False"
                                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label
                                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                        HeightRequest="35"
                                                        Text="{Binding name}"
                                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </xct:Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new SubCatgories();
    }
}
public class SubCatgories : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<TaskClass> catgories { get; set; }
    public ICommand command1 { get; set; }
    private TaskClass _selecteditem;
    public TaskClass selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteditem");
        }
    }

    public SubCatgories()
    {
        catgories = new ObservableCollection<TaskClass>()
        {
            new TaskClass(){icon="favorite.png",name="catgory 1",textColor=Color.Black,subtasks=new ObservableCollection<SubTaskClass>(){
            new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 1"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 2"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 3"}
            } },
             new TaskClass(){icon="check.png",name="catgory 2",textColor=Color.Blue,subtasks=new ObservableCollection<SubTaskClass>(){
            new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 1"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 2"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 3"}
            } },
              new TaskClass(){icon="delete.png",name="catgory 3",textColor=Color.YellowGreen,subtasks=new ObservableCollection<SubTaskClass>(){
            new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 1"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 2"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 3"}
            } },
               new TaskClass(){icon="flag.png",name="catgory 4",textColor=Color.ForestGreen,subtasks=new ObservableCollection<SubTaskClass>(){
            new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 1"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 2"}, new SubTaskClass(){name="sub class 3"}
            } },
        };

        selecteditem = catgories[0];
        command1 = new Command(() => { Console.WriteLine(selecteditem.name); });
    }
  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class TaskClass
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Color textColor { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SubTaskClass> subtasks { get; set; }
}

public class SubTaskClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int taskcategory { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Note: Data items in a ListView are called cells, add ViewCell in [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/).