# Why doesn't CollectionView highlight SelectedItems within RefreshView

Tags: xamarin, collections, view, refresh

I'm getting two collections of data from a web service - the full collection and then a subset of items. The subset should be selected on load. I cannot get the SelectedItems to show as selected in the CollectionView, event though that property is set. I've looked over the Monkeys example and all over the web but can't find an example just like this

View:

```
    <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}">

     <CollectionView x:Name="ExperiencesCollectionView"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Experiences}"
                     SelectedItems="{Binding ProfileExperiences, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple">
               <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                            <Label 
                                   Text="{Binding Description}"/>
          
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</StackLayout>
```

Code Behind:

```
  public partial class ExperiencesPage : ContentPage
    {
        ExperiencesViewModel viewModel;

        public ExperiencesPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = viewModel = new ExperiencesViewModel();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (viewModel.Experiences.Count == 0)
                viewModel.IsBusy = true;
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
  public class ExperiencesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<object> ProfileExperiences { get; set; }
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }
        public string InterestedIn { get; set; }

        public ExperiencesViewModel()
        {
            Title = "My Experiences";
            Experiences = new ObservableCollection<Experience>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
         
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Experiences.Clear();
                //Get these from the REST service
                var experiences = await App.ExperienceManager.GetExperiencesAsync();
                var serviceExperiences = await App.ExperienceManager.GetProfileExperiencesAsync();

                foreach (var exp in experiences)
                {
                    Experiences.Add(exp);
                }

                foreach (var profileExp in serviceExperiences)
                {
                    ProfileExperiences.Add(profileExp);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: According to your description, you want to binding two data of lists in [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data), one is for ItemSource, another is for Selecteditem,I think is is not correct. If you want to display nested data in collectionview, I think you can take a look [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421050/xamarin-forms-populate-list-view-that-is-inside-collection-view) firstly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cherry. That's not quite what I'm after. I've actually worked it out now. Although the second collection contains a subset of the first collection, it's not the actual items in the first collection that are being set in the second. It's working now I explicitly reference items in the Items collection

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solution.